# The turtle.down() does not bring the pen down

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle


def draw_petal():
    """This function draws a singel petal """
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.right(45)
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.right(135)
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.right(45)
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.right(135)


def draw_flower():
    """This function uses the draw_petal function to draw a flower"""
    turtle.left(45)
    draw_petal()
    turtle.left(90)
    draw_petal()
    turtle.left(90)
    draw_petal()
    turtle.left(90)
    draw_petal()
    turtle.left(135)
    turtle.forward(150)


def draw_flower_advanced():
    """This....."""
    draw_flower()
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.up()
    turtle.forward(150)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(150)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.down()


def draw_flower_bed():
    """Theis function......"""
    turtle.up()
    turtle.forward(200)
    turtle.left(180)
    turtle.down()
    draw_flower_advanced()
    draw_flower_advanced()
    draw_flower_advanced()


draw_flower_bed()

turtle.done()
```

============================

For some reason the turtle never touch the canvas so the pen always up.

when im using the pendown() its working , but python 3.6 should have 
the down() function as well , no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assertion is correct that turtle.down() exists in 3.6.  You can also use turtle.pd() as these are both aliases for turtle.pendown().

As a data point, I ran your code exactly as is on my computer and It worked without issue, drawing 3 flowers on the screen.

Perhaps your python installation is corrupted somehow?  You can verify the turtle.down function using the dis library. Run this in the shell:

```
import turtle
import dis
dis.dis(turtle.down)
```

This should produce a lot of output in the form of disassembled byte code.  If it doesn't then your python install is likely corrupted and should be reinstalled.

Comment: Thanks i have changed the version to 3.7 and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The pen should be put down when you want movement to produce lines, and should be picked up when you want movement to not produce lines.

You have them reversed.

```
turtle.up()
turtle.forward(200)
turtle.left(180)
turtle.down()
```

Should be:

```
turtle.down()
turtle.forward(200)
turtle.left(180)
turtle.up()
```

Comment: Maybe he's in Australia.

Comment: at first in want the pen to -not - draw a line , but later im using down() to draw with the function draw_flower_advanced() 3 times... but the pan doesn't draw ....

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the color, `color("red")`.  You may find that the pen actually was down but was drawing with a foreground color that was indistinct from the background color.

Otherwise, your code looks correct and works just fine for me.